# How to retrive the effective dated empid from PS_JOB table

Tags: sql, peoplesoft, sqr

I am new to peoplesoft. I can understand the effective date at a conceptual level, but I am still struggling with it in SQR. How do I retrieve the effective dated empid from PS_JOB table? How do I retrieve the valid empname from ps_names for the retrieved empid? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking about the syntax of a SQL query in SQR?

Answer (score 0):

the current name - from the ps_names_vw view
you can use a similar where clause for the ps_job table.

```
select a.emplid,
       a.name_type,
       a.effdt,
       a.last_name,
       a.first_name,
       a.middle_name,
       a.name_prefix,
       a.name_suffix,
       a.last_name_srch,
       a.first_name_srch,
       a.name_display
  from ps_names a
 where a.effdt = (select max (b.effdt)
                    from ps_names b
                   where b.emplid     = a.emplid and
                         b.name_type  = a.name_type and
                         b.effdt     <= to_date (to_char (sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Join names and job table with their respective effective date. here i have taken A, L, P, S employees assuming you need active employees' names only. if not , you can remove empl_status criterion. Also you need to specify the name_type in the main criterion , otherwise multiple rows may be returned for one emplid.

```
SELECT * FROM PS_NAMES N, PS_JOB J
WHERE N.EMPLID = J.EMPLID
AND N.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(N1.EFFDT) FROM PS_NAMES N1
                WHERE N1.EMPLID= N.EMPLID
                AND N1.NAME_TYPE = N.NAME_TYPE
                AND N1.EFFDT <= SYSDATE)
AND J.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(J1.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB J1
                WHERE J1.EMPLID = J.EMPLID
                AND J1.EMPL_RCD = J.EMPL_RCD
                AND J1.EFFDT <= SYSDATE)
AND J.EFFSEQ = (SELECT MAX(J2.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_JOB J2
                WHERE J2.EMPLID = J.EMPLID
                AND J2.EMPL_RCD = J.EMPL_RCD
                AND J2.EFFDT = J.EFFDT)
AND J.EMPL_STATUS IN ('A','L','P','S')
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query will fetch you the most recent data of an employee with Emplid 'XXX' from PS_JOB

SELECT * FROM PS_JOB J
WHERE J.EMPLID = 'XXX'
AND J.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(J1.EFFDT)
               FROM PS_JOB J1
               WHERE J1.EMPLID =J.EMPLID
               AND J1.EMPL_RCD = J.EMPL_RCD
               AND J1.EFFDT < TRUNC(SYSDATE))
AND J.EMPL_RCD = ( SELECT MAX(J2.EMPL_RCD)
                   FROM PS_JOB J2
                   WHERE J2.EMPLID = J.EMPLID
                   AND J2.EFFDT = J.EFFDT )
AND J.EFFSEQ = ( SELECT MAX(J3.EFFSEQ)
                 FROM PS_JOB J3
                 WHERE J3.EMPLID = J.EMPLID
                 AND J3.EMPL_RCD = J.EMPL_RCD
                 AND J3.EFFDT = J.EFFDT)
ORDER BY J.EMPLID , J.EMPL_RCD, J.EFFDT, J.EFFSEQ